# eclipse hanged with empty dialog

Tags: eclipse, dialog, freeze

I am using Eclipse Indigo on Fedora 16, The problem is during some operation while working on eclipse an empty dialog box appears and eclipse hangs, there is no way to close the dialog except to kill eclipse process from shell.

One such scenario is if there exists a file in eclipse project and i want to replace it with another file with the same name, the empty dialog will appear and eclipse hangs.

Following is screenshot of eclipse with empty dialog.
[image: eclipse hanged with empty dialog]

What could be the fix to this problem.

Comment: Get a thread dump (kill -3) of the Eclipse process and post it please.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1101287/                                   kill -3 <pid> didn't produced anything. I used jstack -l <pid>

Comment: Getting these empty dialogues all the time with Eclipse Juno under Mint, it doesn't block Eclipse though, but nevertheless very annoying. Has anyone raised a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread dump looks completely normal, if you can reproduce this, you should file a bug at eclipse.org. There is probably some missed event somewhere at the SWT level for your configuration. They will be able to help with that.

Comment: This issue is reproducible always. This is blocking my development. I even can't debug anything in eclipse because after clicking the debug button same empty dialog box appears. At first i suspected that there may be some issue with eclipse zip package that i have downloaded from eclipse.org, than i installed the eclipse through yum but same problem. :(

Comment: Can you make this happen from a virgin installation and empty workspace (so that someone at eclipse.org might be able to dup it?) If so, please file a bug and they should be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found the problem (for me anyway)...

I see the problem on Eclipse Juno on Linux Mint using the Cinnamon window manager.
https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/340
says its a bug in Cinnamon and turning off Desktop Effects in Cinnamon will fix it. I did have desktop effects enabled and I turned them off and I haven't been able to make the empty dialog appear after 10 minutes of trying by doing a sequence of steps that always did it for me before. YMMV, but try turning off desktop effects in your window manager.

Comment: I have the same problem on Linux Mint 13 64bit with cinnamon window manager, a temporary workaround is to restart cinnamon wm.

Answer (score 1):

So check if the file .snap exist in your Workbench-Folder on:

> .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources.

Than remove, or rename the file and start eclipse again.

Comment: This will get you going again, but does not address whatever caused the crash. Also see [What are *.snap files in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026502/what-are-snap-files-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar problem when I close Eclipse Juno under Mint Cinnamon. The close dialogue turns into a ghost and sticks around after the process has terminated.

My workaround is to restart the window manager (Alt-F2, r, enter). I realise this isn't quite what the original question asked about, but it seems related.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
rm -rf /path_to_workspace/.plugins
```

What didn't work for me:

```
eclipse -clean
```