# Loading Workspace Snapshot in Eclipse IDE after crash

Tags: eclipse, crash, snapshot

I recently had a system crash and had some unsaved files in Eclipse IDE (Juno). I read on [Eclipse website](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-8.htm) that Eclipse saves snapshots of the workspace. But I am not able to find the snapshot and therefore cant load them. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just restart. Eclipse will automatically restore what it can. See also [What are *.snap files in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026502/what-are-snap-files-in-eclipse)