# Flashbuilder stopped to load at Loading Workbench

Tags: flash-builder

When I press Flashbuilder icon in order to start it up, it stops at splash screen in "Loading Workbench" and stay there forever. It loads only 92804K of memory, according to process manager. How can I fix that? I can't work `t_t`

Answer (score 1):

In [Eclipse/Flash Builder 4.7 Hanging on Loading Workbench](http://bbishop.org/blog/?p=656), Brian Bishop explains that this can happen if the Eclipse/FlashBuilder crash recovery fails. To fix this, you can try the following:

Go to `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources` and delete the `.snap` file.

You won't lose your workspace configuration if you only delete this file.

snap files are explained here: [What are *.snap files in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026502/what-are-snap-files-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by deleting the `.metadata` file, since it is my current workspace. Unfortunately i lost all my configuration.