# Can't open workspace in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

During my work in eclipse kepler it crashed.

Now I can't open eclipse on the requested workspace (on other work space it open fine).

After choosing a workspace I get a pop up message:

`An error has occurred. see the log file. ...WORKSPACE/.metadata/.log`

Opening the log file:

```
!SESSION 2015-03-19 17:10:55.171 -----------------------------------------------

eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2015-03-19 17:10:58.594
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-03-19 17:10:58.910
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (82).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config/web.xml' not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2252)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 29 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config/web.xml' not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2252)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-03-19 17:10:58.969
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (82).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config/web.xml' not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2252)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 29 more
```

- I tried to restart my computer twice (verify no file is locked).
- I tried to remove the server folder.

My latest work isn't committed to SVN.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Answer (score 20):

Found a solution!

I deleted the file: /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap and it solved the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Great, worked. I had to delete .snap and 36.snap and it worked.

Comment: works like a charme

Answer (score 6):

It works after deleting **.snap** from `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`

Answer (score 0):

I think this an error you can't get on it.
Try to move all the work in your workspace in a new workspace because it has to do with the bundle, that is the reason it as crashed previously and it won't work on the same workspace

Answer (score 0):

Delete your workspace. Then open eclipse. 
Take Backup before delete.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that starting from scratch will help him solve his problem,  but not sure how in any way the problem is solved by doing this, he cannot start eclipse and work in the same context he was working before,  this is like saying if your car does not work,  throw it away, and buy a new car,  strange way of solving things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Red Hat Jboss Developer Studio 10.0 (a bundled version of Eclipse), and had this same problem.
Deleting the *.snap file in C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources worked for me. (This is after an unexpected restart that wouldn't allow me to acknowledge the last Eclipse shut-down pop-up.)

As to why deleting it works, according to [What are *.snap files in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026502/what-are-snap-files-in-eclipse):

"*.snap files represent the changes in workspace state of the IDE during the runtime. This is mostly for eclipse crash recovery plan. When a crash happens these files are used to recover the state of the eclipse workspace."

Apparently, if the crash is severe enough, the snap(shot?) file gets corrupted, and cannot get back to a last good state. But getting Eclipse up at all is better than nothing.  You many need to re-import your projects (I had to import my latest one).