# STS launch issue on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, startup-error

I started STS today and an error alert popped up asking me to look at the error log under /Users/salman/springsource/sts-2.6.0.RELEASE/configuration. That log file had the following stacktrace:

```
!SESSION 2012-03-29 10:16:51.910 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=2.9.0.201203011000-RELEASE
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.springsource.sts.ide -keyring /Users/salmanqureshi/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product com.springsource.sts.ide -keyring /Users/salmanqureshi/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-03-29 10:16:54.928
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-03-29 10:16:54.928
!MESSAGE Bundle org.codehaus.groovy_1.8.6.xx-20120301-1300-e36-RELEASE [1323] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.codehaus.groovy 2 0 2012-03-29 10:16:54.928
!MESSAGE The bundle is disabled: "org.eclipse.pde.ui:Disabled via PDE"

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-03-29 10:16:54.930
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

I tried the few solutions listed on this thread [Eclipse freezing at startup - before loading workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657054/eclipse-freezing-at-startup-before-loading-workspace) but nothing worked.

While I go and try a few different things and checkout a few more blog posts. I wouldn't mind getting a quick reply here.

EDIT:
Here's my STS.ini. Does this make any sense kadaj?

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345
-product
com.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-clean
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xmn128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by removing the 'org.eclipse.osgi' folder under configuration and relaunching STS. Got a fresh build of this bundle in configuration folder. I think that is what was corrupted.

Comment: This fixed my problem too. Mine happened after upgrading from GGTS 3.0.0.RELEASE to 3.1.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the mentioned steps

1. Open Application
2. Locate STS
3. Right click and open package contents
4. navigate to eclipse folder
5. open sts.ini
6. Add -Xss128m -Xmn1024m