# Eclipse/STS starts once - then fails to start again - Mac/Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: eclipse, macos, sts

After trying to install a CVS client into Eclipse/STS (ver 4.7.1) that I use no longer loads.  I've re-installed Eclipse/STS a couple of times, but the startup issue persists...I get the exceptions listed below.  On intermittent tries after deleting the .metadata/ folder from the workspace, it sometimes loads.  But once I close it and try to re-open it never starts on that workspace again.

Things I've tried from other (older) stack-overflow posts :

- Reinstalling STS, a couple of time...the CVS client "should" no longer be an issue...It's not even installed on the re-installed version.
- Deleting the workspace.xmi file.

Nothing seems to work...And from the stacktrace below, I can't tell what the NullPointerException is referring to.  I did verify there is a LegacyIDE.e4xmi file in the location indicated, and I have R/W permissions to it.

Here are the errors in the .log I see.

```
!SESSION 2020-09-29 13:03:57.621 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.202007271558-RELEASE
java.version=1.8.0_261
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 -keyring /Users/n0002501/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 -keyring /Users/[myuser]/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-09-29 13:04:13.603
!MESSAGE Unable to load resource platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-09-29 13:04:13.630
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

Comment: **Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder** since it does not only contain caches but also stuff you don't want to lose! Deleting the `.metadata` folder is a hoax spread on Stack Overflow and has already caused problems for many. If `-clean` does not help, use a fresh workspace (`-data <workspace-dir>` or _File > Switch Workspace_) having its own `.metadata` folder instead.

Comment: @howlger, AH, forgot about the -clean arg...On windows I always had that on all my shortcuts...Just added it to my Mac Automator script...TY!  For the .metadata/, will denote this going forward.

Comment: People might delete the `.metadata` folder because they read your question without my comment and lose data that took them many hours to create. Please help to prevent this Stack Overflow hoax from spreading even further.

Comment: @howlger, Done, I removed that line...hth, adym

Comment: Thanks! That's nice.

Answer (score 0):

Figures, as soon as I post the question, I found a solution here :

[STS launch issue on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919820/sts-launch-issue-on-mac)

Posted 8 years ago...but it works now.  For anyone experiencing this, that org.eclipse.osgi folder is buried in the Mac SpringToolSuite.app contents...which is what the NullPointerException in the stacktrace lists.

I can only surmise that installation of the CVS Client left that in a corrupt state, but I would've thought a Re-install would have gotten rid of it.

Comment: The problem is in your workspace directory not in the installation.