# Why does RAD 8 consistently hang on startup?

Tags: eclipse, rad

I am experiencing a problem where Rational Application Developer 8 consistently hangs indefinitely on startup. I've only been able to find a partial solution: I can get RAD to start up if I delete the <*n*>.tree file in the workspace's .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.root directory.  Once started however, all projects must be re-imported.

What I can't seem to solve is the underlying issue -- the issue recurs after every shutdown of RAD, and I'm having to delete the .tree file and re-import the projects each time I start the app. Shutting down RAD normally does not prevent the problem from recurring; neither does removing all projects and cycling RAD with no projects (problems start again immediately the first time RAD is shut down with projects still imported).  I've even created a new workspace from scratch, but it didn't help either.

I'm at a loss.  If anyone has experienced this, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: RAD has problems, Eclipse with Tomcat is better.

Comment: Did RAD generate any errors in the error log?  <workspace>/.metadata/.log

Comment: Good question Paul; I forgot to mention that the only message in error log was a warning that the application had not been shut down properly in the prior session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently experiencing the same problem with an older version of RAD and haven't found a working solution yet so far, but you might get some pointers from here:
[How do I prevent Eclipse from hanging on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207843/how-do-i-prevent-eclipse-from-hanging-on-startup)

At any rate, you can check the ./metadata/.log file in your workspace for useful information about where exactly it hangs.

Answer (score 1):

There are many background process starts when Eclipse or RAD starts. You can disable the background process which is not required. These can be found under Window->Preferences->General->Startup and Shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Temp files under /tmp folder and restart RAD...

Worked for me...