# Eclipse won't start but no error is shown

Tags: eclipse

Any idea why my Eclipse isn't starting?

The `eclipse.ini` has the following:

```
-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.0.v20100503
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M
-showsplash org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

The error log in workspace log file shows this

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2011-10-21 12:03:18.134
>   !MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous
>   session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-10-21 12:03:19.447 !MESSAGE An error
>   occurred while automatically activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources (68). !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383) Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element
>   '/webtop/.classpath' not found.   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:517)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1503)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:1883)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:406)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     ... 29 more Root exception:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element
>   '/webtop/.classpath' not found.   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:517)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1503)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:1883)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:406)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-10-21 12:03:19.467 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383) Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException:
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources (68).  at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  ... 14 more
>   Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
>     ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element
>   '/webtop/.classpath' not found.   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:517)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1503)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:1883)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:406)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     ... 29 more

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042824/not-able-to-run-eclipse-application-cant-even-start-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 165, accepted):

It seems to fail when trying to restore the workspace.

Try:

1. Open a new workspace. If it has been set to use a default, go to 
   `<Eclipse_root_dir>\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` and set `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` to true
2. Try deleting `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap`
3. As suggested in a comment: If using Eclipse 4, you may have to delete the file `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` aswell.

Comment: Thanks that works. Eclipse opens but it doesn't show my projects and packages

Comment: If you have a new workspace you will have to import them again.

Comment: I had to delete both of the following files as suggested in other answers to solve my issue,

.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi

Comment: Suggestion 3 worked for me also. I could not find any .snap file, btw.

Comment: Seriously, how do you know such details? Are you one of eclipse developers? Thanks, deleting .snap did the trick.

Comment: Suggestion 3 worked for me too. I am running, Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

Answer (score 13):

**This is my solution:**

- delete the file **.snap** located inside:

  **`<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/`**
- delete the file: **workbench.xmi** located inside:

  **`<workspace>.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/`**

Then you will not have problems accessing to your Eclipse.

**My old solution:**

This problem is **caused mainly by a corrupt workspace**, i had the choice of create a new `workspace` but i had the projects linked to `Subversion`, so i needed preferently keep the same projects inside my original `workspace`, now i want to expose my solution:

inside the `workspace` into the folder `.metadata`, delete all the files inside:

[image]

then import again your projects `File` -> `Import` -> `Existing Projects into Workspace`

[image]

Comment: It worked for me with ONLY deleting the .snap file on iOS. Appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @PK'  in fact i was using OSx when i found that solution.

Answer (score 8):

There is a `.metadata` directory in your workspace. Within it, there is a file named `.log` - if the startup process does not fail *very* early, it should contain useful error messages.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem of not being able to start eclipse after a bad crash in windows and deleting the workspace settings did not help. Reinstalling eclipse did not help. I had to uninstall and install Java and I could run Eclipse again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the jdk installed. If it persists try downloading a new copy of eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse quit launching for me after a Windows XP System Restore. When I re-downloaded the new version of Java it started working again.

Comment: If you are getting the stack trace listed in the question the problem is failing *Eclipse* session recovery after a crash. Upgrading JDK/JRE only helps if java version is changed enough to force Eclipse to skip session recovery. Removing the `*.snap` files will force Eclipse to skip session recovery for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I tried removing the

`org.eclipse.core.resources` from safe table, restart eclipse, you should be able to see all the configuration, but you won't be able to see your project, that you might
have to import.

Cut  `org.eclipse.core.resources` from safe table

Restart Eclipse
then copy back your the org.eclipse.core.resources

and then restart.(but you have to import the project for sure, )
from `C:\Workspace_BR-12-Q3-MPSERS-REFORM\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.safetable`

This seems lie it will happen when you have multiple trees in your workspace.

Answer (score 2):

I have to re install jre and it's work!, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**
Flash Builder or Eclipse won't start. This happens when it is shut down incorrectly (like when your laptop battery dies).

**Solution**
Delete the workspace .snap file.

**Steps**
First, show hidden files. You can do this by opening Terminal and setting Finder's show all files property to true. You must also restart Finder for the changes to take effect.

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

Delete the Eclipse snap file. To do this navigate to your Eclipse workspace. In that directory you'll find the hidden .metadata directory. Navigate to ".metadata/.plugins/com.eclipse.core.resources/". In that directory you'll see a file called ".snap". Make sure Eclipse is closed (not open and not stuck on the splash screen). Next delete the ".snap" file.

[image]

Restart Eclipse. Once it is working set the hidden folders back to hidden with:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
killall Finder
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your installations
eclipse\configuration.settings folder

edit
org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs to show workspace=true

Create a new workspace
Run eclipse again
Import your project from previous workspace

Answer (score 0):

Erase the old `.metadata` folder from the workspace and copy the new one that was created somewhere I chosen the first time.

**Background:** I had a similar problem and it started when I uninstalled the eclipse and installed it again, so at the first time I created a new workspace, I work without any problem, then another time I chose the old workspace, so when I tried to open it, it used the old `.metadata` folder.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I somehow installed 32-bit Java and screwed up my environment variables so the jdk1.7.0_10 wasn't in PATH any more. Fixed it from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431822/how-do-i-install-a-jre-or-jdk-to-run-the-android-developer-tools-on-windows-7), following the poster's screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the right bit version of Java. I had 32 bit on 64 bit computer. Do verify your java version here - https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

Proved to be very handy when I installed the right version!