# How do I install a JRE or JDK to run the Android Developer Tools on Windows 7?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm trying to install the Android Developer Tools on my Windows 7 computer, so that I can use the Android emulator to test websites.

Android Developer's website, "[Setting Up the ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html)":

> The ADT Bundle provides everything you need to start developing apps... If you haven't already, go download the Android ADT Bundle.
>
> ...
>
> #### Install the SDK and Eclipse IDE
>
> Unpack the ZIP file (named adt-bundle-.zip) and save it to an appropriate location, such as a "Development" directory in your home directory.
>   Open the adt-bundle-/eclipse/ directory and launch eclipse.
>   That's it! The IDE is already loaded with the Android Developer Tools plugin and the SDK is ready to go.

My computer, after I carried out those exact steps:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
>   C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
>   javaw.exe in your current PATH

How do I get a Java Runtime Environment or Java Development Kit that will let me run the Android Developer Tools bundle?

(And, for bonus points, why isn't it included in the download, if the download is meant to provide "everything you need to start developing apps"?)

Comment: @arne.b: Ah - I have taken the unreasonable step of not having worked with Java before.

Comment: You can download the SDK from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: I totally agree that if it states that it includes everything than it should be able to run from a fresh windows install, otherwise list the requirements needed.

Comment: To answer your bonus question: the JDK is not included because Oracle's license would require Google to pay for each and every download/installation. So they simply cannot distribute it this way.

Comment: @allprog: aha! Gotcha. Whereas if we download it ourselves, it’s free. For some reason. Thanks Oracle!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can go [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp) to download the Java JRE.

You can go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to download the Java JDK.

After that you need to set up your environmental variables in Windows:

1. Right-click **My Computer**
2. Click **Properties**
3. Go to **Advanced System Settings**
4. Click on the **Advanced** tab
5. Click on **Environment Variables**

**EDIT:** See screenshot for environmental variables

[image]

Comment: I have Java installed already. (Or at least I have a Java Control Panel. It is 32-bit though, whereas my Windows 7 is 64-bit.)

Comment: Looks like your current path variable is set incorrectly. It should point to your java bin folder in your program files directory.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: You need the JDK, JRE is not enough. Also, it has to be in your `Path`

Comment: @Neil: aha, I see. I have two of those: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin` and C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`. When I type in `PATH` on the command line I get `PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\
Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64`. Any idea whether I should add JRE 6 or 7 to my path?

Comment: I would add JRE 7. But like @jlordo said. You should also install the JDK. After you installed that you can point your path to the JDK bin folder. See my updated answer

Comment: @Neil: indeedy, just installing the SDK now. That's really helpful re the environment variables: a thoroughly deserved acceptance coming your way once I've got it working.

Comment: Is it necessary to install both?

Comment: I think if you only install the JDK it adds a JRE automatically.

Answer (score 4):

download jre1.7.0_45 and then extract it into the Eclipse folder and rename folder of jre1.7.0_45 to jre and Eclipse will run

Answer (score 1):

you need to download and install `jdk` from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If using win7 64 bit OS:

After installing the latest JDK make sure you copy the jre folder from the install location {`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40`} directly to your eclipse folder as even pathing it apparently does nothing on win7.

Mad

edit:

Actual jdk version number on folder name will vary as newer versions are released

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have 64-bit `eclipse` running but you have 32 bit `JRE`.So please download `JRE` for 64 bit `windows` and let it install on the default location.
Finally add that path till bin in your PATH variable.
Try it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse: failed to create the java virtual machine – message box

1. Open folder with Eclipse.exe and find eclipse.ini file
2. Replace -vmargs by your current real path of javaw.exe with

   ```
   -vm "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javaw.exe"
   ```

   or in case you've installed jre only:

   ```
   -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason why the Java Runtime Environment JRE or Java Development Kit JDK is that it's owned by Oracle not Google and they would need a redistribution agreement which if you know there is some history between the two companies.

Lucky for us that Sun Microsystems before it was bought by Oracle open sourced Java and MySQL a win for us little guys.... Thank you Sun!

Google should probably have a caveat saying you may also need JRE OR JDK