# SDK can`t find jdk

Tags: java, android, sdk

User variables:
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
(also `ve try with JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre8)

System variables
PATH = ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Windows 8.1 Enterprise - x64
jdk - x64
SDK Bundle(from android site) - x64

When i try to open SDK Manager:
"'C:\Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. The system cannot find the path specified."

When i check the version of java in cmd its ok. But SDK still can`t find it.

I need help to open android SDK Manager. I`ve read all similar post no one helps.

Comment: Did you try this- http://stackoverflow.com/a/15431928/713778

Comment: Yes but it do not helps