# App gets stuck on splash screen when running in the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, splash-screen, android-virtual-device

When running in the emulator the splash screen gets stuck and never starts the next activity. I removed the splash Activity from the manifest file and made the next Activity as my launcher.  Still, when I run the app I get the splash screen. I have done everything like restarting eclipse, made new avd but I don't know from where it is getting the splash screen. I don't know why this is happening.

This works fine when running on a device, the issue only occurs when running in the emulator.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kaizen"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.kaizen.Login"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: can you show your java code?

Comment: Did you make a copy of your project? It is possible that you are making changes in one code while your launch configuration is running another project (which may be your older copy of the project).

Comment: show you splash page java code

Comment: show me what have you done in activity kiran...

Comment: @KartikKaushik no I have only one copy. If I running app in real device it works fine only emulator is causing problem.  but i have to run app in emulator also.

Comment: Check "Wipe user data" before you launch the emulator and then re-install the app.

Comment: Hi Rohit. ok I'm posting the code.

Comment: @KartikKaushik could you please tell me how to wipe data or emulator.

Comment: in this code, you show login page as first page.

Comment: then you probably have problem with cache or old app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to uninstall all JRE 7 and install latest JRE 6 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre6downloads-1902815.html). It will immediately fixed the problem.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15431928/3828908) for installation help

Comment: please tell me how to delete jre 7? from eclipse folder?

Comment: @Anita  Window-->Preferences-->Java-->Installed JREs

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall app from emulator and then re run your app. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Anita are you sure no dubugger is attached?

Comment: @Salmaan no I'm running the app. I tried to debug but it is also not working.

Comment: @Salmaan I'm sorry I  did not notice that I have an error in ddms "can't  bind to local 8601 for debugger"

Comment: @Anita did you fixed the issue?

Comment: @Salmaan   No I don't understand how to fix the debugger problem