# Java SE Development kit didn't installed right?

Tags: java, java-8, missing-data

First off, let me say I did all of this while watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl-zzrqQoSE

So, I tried downloads jdk-8u60 for windows 64bit, as seen right here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (JDK), but when I first installed my antivirus Avira did a system scam, I don't remember if it was for java or not, but just pointing out.

I also got a strange error, saying that there is a missing file inside the bin folder (I can't get that error again, sorry folks). When I try to run "javac" on CMD it says "java is not recognized as an internal or external file" (my computer is not on english, sorry), so I went to check and the folder is like this:

[image]

As I can see, there is a **lot** of missing files compared to the guy's videos, and I wonder what could have gone wrong.

I tried:

- Doing the rest of the video to see if it could at least works
- Running the installer again (it runned completely fine, like if it was first time, but did no stuff). On the first try I got that same error, but lately I haven't got it again
- Checked other folders

I can't see to find the solution. Any help?

Comment: You added the environment variables ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

Comment: make the use of "Path" command it will help you understand the error.

Comment: **Ced**: if you mean as in the video, them yeah.
**SnakeDoc**: Going to check that out
**Vinayak Pingale**: Yep I tryed running javac at CMD, didn't worked

Comment: If you installed jdk, why does your screenshot only show the jre folder? And not only that but it also shows an earlier version of jre8 (update 25) while you say you have installed version 8 update 60

Comment: screenshot only shows jre not jdk - can you verify you installed the JDK? i.e. what's under `/Java`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a JRE or JDK to run the Android Developer Tools on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431822/how-do-i-install-a-jre-or-jdk-to-run-the-android-developer-tools-on-windows-7)

Comment: that's very strange indeed: http://prntscr.com/88v7yo

Comment: guys, I downloaded the x86 version, and my system is 64 bits. a guy said that x64 is for 64 and x86 is for 36, so I will reinstall

Comment: Ok I solved my problem guys, apparently I have a 64 bits system and downloaded x86 JDK. I fully uninstalled it and downloaded x64 and it now works perfectly! But thanks for the "path" thing, I forgot where I got the video anyway (and its going to help some other people too :D)

Comment: You can use the x86 version on Windows_x64 without problems. But the x86 version will be installed into a different directory (“Program Files (x86)” in English) than the x64 software. You were looking into the wrong directory and seeing the relicts of an older, improperly uninstalled x64 version rather than the newly installed x86 version. Nevertheless, installing an x64 version is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the JDK bin to your path. You can do this by going to Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > System Variables > path > edit. Then, you need to add this to the path:
`;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

WARNING: this is highly dangerous! if you delete parts of the path, your computer might not function properly! Be extremely Careful!

Comment: but that's what I did (as I saw on the video), I did everything on the video.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I downloaded the wrong java, my system is 64 bits (which means x64) and I downloaded JDK x86 (which is 32 bits). Just deleting all the JDK and JEK files and reinstalling using the correct one completely fixes it. Remember to use the "path" fix too:

> Blockquote
>   You need to add the JDK bin to your path. You can do this by going to
>   Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System
>   Settings > Environment Variables > System Variables > path > edit.
>   Then, you need to add this to the path: ;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
>
> WARNING: this is highly dangerous! if you delete parts of the path,
>   your computer might not function properly! Be extremely Careful!

-Ethan Ferguson