# eclipse won't load workspace

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I was working in eclipse, and it got stuck, and next it refused to load my usual workspace folder

this is what the logfile shows

how can i load this folder again?

```
!SESSION 2013-08-21 14:27:21.896 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Dev\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2013-08-21 14:27:29.774

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-08-21 14:27:29.774
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logging(PlatformLogWriter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.log(RuntimeLog.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2412)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-08-21 14:27:29.789
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-08-21 14:27:29.789
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-08-21 14:27:29.789
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:809)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.handleException(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2412)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 4 0 2013-08-21 14:27:29.789
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin$TasksUiStartup.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2412)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui (288).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/mylyn/monitor/ui/IUserAttentionListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui (281).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.monitor.ui.MonitorUiPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.asyncExec(Display.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.monitor.ui.MonitorUiPlugin.start(MonitorUiPlugin.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: there is usally a popup with some short info. what does it say?

Comment: "look in .metadata/.log"  this is it

Comment: Delete the `.metadata` folder. It's where eclipse stores workspace info. It will reset all of your workspace settings, but won't affect projects.

Comment: I followed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310970/eclipse-juno-doesnt-start/12045547#12045547) and it worked perfectly for me. This solution keeps the workspace configuration as it is.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
Deleting **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi** worked. I am not sure of the root cause, though.

**OR**

Move the contents of **"plugins"** folder to some other folder and restart eclipse. Eclipse will add all these plugins after restart. Replace the new folders with the copied folders.

Comment: deleting the metadata forced me to reinstall all plugins, and redo the shortcuts - however, moving the metadata to external folder, opening the folder and then restoring the metadata did the trick!

Comment: i should read the comments sometimes - i posted this comment last time my workspace crashed, and now that i've read it, i missed who posted it, if i could thumbsup your answer again, i would, thanks for your help!

Comment: i should get some sleep, it took me few minutes to figure the .metadata dir is in the workspace dir itself

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly for me. It just restored windows etc to the original state.

Comment: The problem in my case was I was trying to compare a very large file with another using the eclipse plugin. I suspect this occurs when eclipse is not able to perform such a heavy process and gets stuck.

Comment: The first solution saved me a lot of time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

Removing the .snap file worked for me:

rm WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap

Comment: Deleting the entire .metadata directory was the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Just linking the solution provided by Fredrik in the thread: [eclipse won't start but no error is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847359/eclipse-wont-start-but-no-error-is-shown)

"It seems to fail when trying to restore the workspace.

Try:

Open a new workspace. If it has been set to use a default, go to \configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs and set SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG to true

Try deleting /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap

As suggested in a comment: If using Eclipse 4, you may have to delete the file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi aswell."

Comment: The answer above didn't work for me, but this fixed it.

Comment: even for me deleting the file 25.snap fixed it.