# Error after updating ADT in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Last version of ADT in my eclipse was API 16, so I updated ADT (eclipse->Help->Install new software->Work with: ADT ) and then multiple errors occurred!!!

I can not even open Android SDK Manager !

There are some Screenshots from error :

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I roll it back?!

P.s : Before Updating ADT I tried to add "SQLiteManager" PLugin by copying a jar file into "eclipse/dropins/" folder, but eclipse did not run anymore. So I removed the jar file and eclipsed lunched successfully!

Comment: Jessica, you have to update your ADT to version 23.0, I have suffered with this error, its like a nightmare for me. But one thing is clear that you have to process all the steps from scratch, just download new sdk, then update latest ADT.

Comment: I suggest you to install Android Studio, in future this is must needed thing Jessica.

Answer (score 1):

Update your ADT Plugin

open HELP > About Eclipse > Installation Details

And also update Android SDK with 23.0.0

Comment: No Updates Were Found!

Comment: Look, I Updated my ans

Answer (score 1):

Recently i faced the same problem, it simply fails to update. It was mainly due to a packaging bug of Android. This is a problem many people might face. here is the workaround:

1. Go to Help (in Eclipse)> about Eclipse SDK> Installation details and remove Android Development Tools (ADT).
2. Go to Help (in Eclipse) > install new software > beside the 'work with' box click ''Add'' , type ADT as name and as location give this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. Then you will see developer tools, select Android development tools from there and click Finish.
   this should update your Android Development tools and solves many other consequential issues while updating SDK. So, basically you have to remove your old ADT and then only you can update from Google' repo given in the URL.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I removed ADT23 and then updated again with your link. when eclipse restarted `An error has occurred. see the log file .....`. Now I can not even run eclipse ! :(

Comment: well, if you reinstalled ADT successfully this should not have happened, that's weird !

Comment: any success in launching eclipse?

Comment: Yeah, I used this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847359/eclipse-wont-start-but-no-error-is-shown) and eclipse lunched then I uninstalled ADT23. In next step I downloaded ADT22.zip and now I'm trying to update ADT offline !

Comment: you may need to install/update Android SDK tools and Android SDK platform tools from SDK manager, Android SDK manager will reappear on your eclipse if you manage to successfully setup ADT i guess.

Comment: I successfully update eclipse to `ADT 22` but still I can not see API Level 17/18 or 19 in SDK Manager to download them !!!

Comment: did u restart eclipse after updating ADT? after restarting try reloading SDK manager. i faced exactly this problem, SDK levels were not listed in SDK manager.

Comment: yes it automatically restarted. I faced this problem before updating and now the problem still persist! Also the main problem solved by offline updating! Finally I prefer to update API level offline :D