# Android - ADT Update Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have updated Android SDK's after restarting it says Update ADT (As shown in image below). Then I tried to update it from `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` and `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` this too. But it says,

`Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
  Software currently installed: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT XML Overlay 23.0.3.1327240 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.3.1327240)
    ADT XML Overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.3.1327240]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]`

What should I do to run my Eclipse properly? I never faced this weird issue.

[image: ADT Update]

Comment: @Mitesh few days before facing the same issue...I update it to version 23 and got stuck...so u need to replace whole eclipse folder.Download packages for earlier version.http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/index.html#download

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22525464/3819810

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472966/cannot-complete-the-install-because-of-a-conflicting-dependency

Comment: @james & Indiandroid: Guys no other way than reinstalling whole eclipse. Because it will take my whole day. :(

Comment: @user3819810 and Piyush Kukadiya: Thank you, will try it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to download new eclipse and do all repeat steps.

Easy Steps to work around this :-
**1.** Go to Help -> about eclipse ->Installation Details.

**2.** Uninstall all previous version of android(like has 22.xx and id as com.android.xxx)
**3.** Restart Eclipse.
**4.** Now Go to Help -> install new software ->select android ADT site and install the new version of 23.xx.
I have posted these steps because I have just half hour ago updated my eclipse with new version from 22.xx to 23.xx without any error.
 Hope this will help you too.

[image: android version update]

Comment: The "Uninstall Button" is disabled.. :(

Comment: while updating had you faced conflict with the version while installing android developement tools..?

Comment: Yes. Please check my Question

Comment: can you confirm one thing that :- In installation details->Installed stoftware-> click on android ddms and check uninstall button is still disabled or not

Comment: OK then finally my suggesion that go through this question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23?lq=1

Comment: I already visited that que. and doing the same which is mentioned in the answer by @Lalit. Eclipse update is under progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59708/discussion-between-pravin-and-mitesh).

Answer (score 1):

Update Android SDK with 23.0.0

Update your ADT Plugin
open HELP > About Eclipse > Installation Details

or see below link

[Error after updating ADT in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402909/error-after-updating-adt-in-eclipse/25403027#25403027)

Answer (score 0):

i got the same thing in the begining and tried this(no need to uninstall eclipse again, take more time) just follow these steps saves ur time

hope this helps u

click on help **install new software** - there u can find **Available software sites** click on this , u can see, Eclipse, android, indigo, but uninstall the **android adt plugin from there**, and install the adt plugin again.