# Eclipse no longer opens

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I logged into my PC and as usual started up Eclipse (Eclipse Luna). It was not opening. I downloaded the newest Eclipse (Eclipse Mars) and it started at first so I installed my theme. This required a restart but it didn't open back up. I also could not open it back up, when I try to nothing happens. Nothing loads. I have tried running as administrator and that did not work. I have also looked online and tried to see if it was the `eclipse.ini` but adding the vm to that still didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: [Relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847359/eclipse-wont-start-but-no-error-is-shown)

Comment: You will have to provide more information: what operating system do you use, how did you remove *Eclipse*, etc. Now we can only guess out of thousands of reasons why it is not working.

Comment: try by removing .metadata file present in the workspace. THen it might work...Otherwise provide the exact help....

Comment: For the sake of testing run Eclipse under a different account which does not have any Eclipse specific data in its profile

Comment: @resueman, looked there. It didn't solve my issue
Naruto, tried :/

Answer (score 0):

In these circumstances, if you can afford please do try the following.

1. Reinstall the Eclipse, since it only takes few minutes and might be worth saving all of the hassle.
2. If you are using a specific theme, check if that theme is compatible with the  version of Eclipse that you are using. You may want to use a different theme, if that is ok to try to see if the issue persists.

Easiest approach may be just reinstall Eclipse.

Comment: resueman already provided a link to a comprehensive solution

Comment: Reinstalled but again it wouldn't open

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem briefly when I updated java and allowed the installer to remove obsolete versions of jvm.  The installer had installed a 32bit vm and
removed 64 bit vms.   Reinstall the current 64bit vm.