# Eclipse hangs on startup

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, slackware

I have problem with running my Eclipse. I tried 3.7, 4.2 and 4.3 versions with java 6 and java 7.  Nothing can help me. It shows me popup screen but it doesn't start to load( I dont have chance to choose workspace).
Starting it with `-debug -console` parameters shows that it stops running in this moment:

```
Time to load bundles: 10
Starting application: 6374
osgi>
```

I have started JVisualVM but I cannot observe anything special. There are no deadlocks etc.

**Edit**

My observations were to deep... After ~60s pid of eclipse is dead.

**Edit 2**

Now it stops on

```
Time to load bundles: 8
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Starting application: 3557
```

**Edit 3**

I have managed to start it but only with `-clean` parameter and with choosing workspace from command line `-data` parameter.

Comment: You want `-consoleLog` and not `-console`, I believe.

Comment: Jup, had the same problem. Obviously there's a problem with the workspace detection, the -data parameter solved it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem and could solve it using the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5504530/1275767 which works by moving the projects out of the workspace and back in again after Eclipse has been started and stopped.

Starting it with -clean -data  started eclipse but whenever I switched the workspace using the eclipse gui it wouldn't load.

Comment: I happen to have the same problem with Eclipse RCP 2019, every few days I need to reimport projects into a new workspace due to this problem. Clearly this is not very usable solution, since it clears all the workspace state.

Answer (score 17):

Remove .snap (or .markers in Indigo) from  .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\\

Comment: I removed the .snap files from my workspace folder under .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders and I think this fixed it.

Comment: Did the same and it works, but after that my workspace and all the projects were lost. Had to setup it again.

Answer (score 1):

With Eclipse Kepler, you need to remove all of the .snap files within the .plugins directory, i.e. C:...\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32.metadata.plugins. Once I did that, everything started up fine. (NOTE: There are about 10 *.snap files total)

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit `workbench.xml` in the `\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\` folder
2. remove all the coding in XML File in between `<editor></editor>` in the `<editors></editors>`
3. save the xml file and close the eclipse platform and restart your Eclipse and it should run properly

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't solve these problems with any of the above options on mars or neon. Downgraded to Luna, which also happens to be the version that I had deleted previously. This worked for me.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. Downgrading is usually not the preferred option, but it is an option that may help someone out.

Comment: It might be a problem with GTK 3. You can tell Eclipse to use GTK 2, by configuring eclipse.ini file
```--launcher.GTK_version```
```2```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the above options, nothing worked. So I finally figured out the solution:
I removed all JRE installations in my C:\Program Files and C:|Program Files(x86) folders. Installed a new JDK 7 package, copied the fullpath of JDK7\bin folder and appended it at the end of the "Path" variable found under 'Environment variables' of my Windows 7 pc. Then restarted everything, so it worked.