# eclipse MARS won't start after splash screen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I'm running eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04 and my eclipse MARS was working find until I tried opening it today. I can see the splash screen for a while until it disappears and nothing happens after that. I tried opening it using terminal and it gives me the following and just hangs forever!

> [Fatal Error] :16727:5848: Premature end of file.
>
> org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The
>   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the
>   state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location
>   is initialized.

I tried restarting the machine, running it with -clean option but nothing works. This is so frustrating. What should I do?

**EDIT**
I ran it with -consoleLog and below is its output. 
Seems to me like it fails to load a file as her: `

> Caused by: org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The file
>   /home/sam/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1443583842385.profile.gz
>   of length 118971 failed to load properly

below is the full length output.

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2015-09-30
>   15:59:43.827 !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
>   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The
>   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the
>   state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location
>   is initialized. !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception
>   in
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start()
>   of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil$ReflectionException:
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The file
>   /home/sam/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1443583842385.profile.gz
>   of length 118971 failed to load properly  at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.containsProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.containsProfile(ProfilePreferences.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.load(ProfilePreferences.java:253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:676)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:676)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getPreferences(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:503)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:181)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:649)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The
>   file
>   /home/sam/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1443583842385.profile.gz
>   of length 118971 failed to load properly  at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.loadProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfile.getDelegate(LazyProfile.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfile.getDelegate(LazyProfile.java:83)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfile.getProperty(LazyProfile.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.updateSelfProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:147)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
>     ... 41 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature end of file.
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry$Parser.parse(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:734)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry$Parser.parse(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:720)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.loadProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:256)
>     ... 50 more Root exception:
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil$ReflectionException:
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The file
>   /home/sam/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1443583842385.profile.gz
>   of length 118971 failed to load properly  at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:214)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.containsProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.containsProfile(ProfilePreferences.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.load(ProfilePreferences.java:253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:676)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:676)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getPreferences(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:503)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:181)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:649)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The file
>   /home/sam/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1443583842385.profile.gz
>   of length 118971 failed to load properly  at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.loadProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:264)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfile.getDelegate(LazyProfile.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfile.getDelegate(LazyProfile.java:83)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfile.getProperty(LazyProfile.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.updateSelfProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:147)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
>     ... 41 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature end of file.
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry$Parser.parse(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:734)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry$Parser.parse(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:720)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.loadProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:256)
>     ... 50 more Starting application: 2153

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450500/eclipse-hangs-on-startup

Comment: @BalwindeSingh thanks!