# Eclipse only running with -clean -refresh

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

My eclipse will only open if I run it from the terminal like so

> /Users/Me/Documents/eclipse/eclipse -clean -refresh

How can I make it open normally? Right now if I try to, it hangs right in the middle.

I have also tried

```
rm /Users/Me/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.lock
```

this is the repeated error in the log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-02-05 16:58:18.820
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-02-05 15:26:07.148
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
!SESSION 2014-02-05 16:58:15.519 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/William/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/Me
```

/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to avoid using -clean altogether?

If not, you can always add the "-clean" value at the first line of your eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory.

Comment: I would like to know the root of the problem so that I could avoid it altogether, my curiosity wants to know why this happens. But this is potentially a better short term solution then always running it from the terminal.

Comment: You could look at the log file in the .metadata directory of your workspace: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F. Also, there might be other logs in your configuration directory of eclipse.

Comment: as a note you must add the args right under -startup for it to work, so like this, -startup
-clean
-refresh

Comment: i added the repetitive error that seems to be the cause.

Comment: Here is a potential solution that I've used in the past: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207843/how-do-i-prevent-eclipse-from-hanging-on-startup. Or you can try this one: http://dev.zhourenjian.com/blog/2007/11/07/eclipse-freezing-on-start.html